# Set up a while loop in celery task

Tags: python, celery

I want to have a while loop going continuously in the background on my web server. I still want to have possibility to turn on and off the loop using flask giving command to my celery worker. The while loop in celery seems only run once.

```
from celery import Celery    
@app.task
    def count(i):
        if i == 1:  # turn on command
            while True:  # a while loop to achieve what I want to do
                i = i+1
                return i
        elif i == 0: # turn off command given by flask
            return i
```

I also tried celery_beat, but this requires me to give arguments in advance rather than accepting command from another source.

```
app.conf.update(
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-1-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.count',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        #'args': (1)
    },
})
```

Comment: You have a `return` inside the while loop. That's why it stops.

Comment: The down votes are just because this isn't how you should use Celery. If you need a process running all the time just create one, using Celery would just be an unnecessary complication. Queue the task every few seconds if you need to, but Celery tasks should be finite.

Comment: Hi thanks for explanation. However, I want this background process to be callable only when needed. I am also accessing remotely through ssh or webinterface and hoping the process will keep running even if I log out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @dim's answer. The code I have now is:

```
@app.task
def count(i):
    if i == 1:
        while True:  # a while loop to achieve what I want to do
            i = i+1
            time.sleep(1)
            print i
            print 'i am counting'
```

To start the worker:

```
$ celery -A tasks worker -l info
```

And call it from python

```
>> from tasks import count
>> result = count(1)
```

To stop the loop from python

```
>> result.revoke(terminate=True)
```

Hope this will be useful for people wanting to have loop in their celery task.